# how to make collection_select value as link_to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, reporting

I have the ff:

### **app/views/reports/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Reports</h1>
<br>

<legend>Categories</legend>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span5">
    <ol>
      <li><%= link_to 'COMMENDATION', commendations_path(format: 'pdf'), { id: 'commendations_click' } %></li>

<%= collection_select(nil, 
                      :employee_id, 
                      @employees, 
                      :id, 
                      :last_name, 
                      {:prompt => "Select an Employee"}, 
                      {:id => 'employees_select'}) %>
<br>
<%= collection_select(nil, 
                      :employee_movement_id, 
                      @employeemovements, 
                      :id, 
                      :position, 
                      {:prompt => "-"}, 
                      {:id => 'employee_movements_select'}) %>

      <li><%= link_to 'REPORT2', '#' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'REPORT3', '#' %></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#employees_select').change(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= update_employee_movements_path %>",
        data: { employee_id : $('#employees_select').val() },
        dataType: "script"
      });
    });

    $('#commendations_click').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= commendations_path %>",
        data: { 
          employee_id : $('#employees_select').val(),
          employee_movement_id : $('#employee_movements_select').val()
        },
        dataType: "script"
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

### **app/controllers/reports_controller**

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # GET /reports
  def index
    @employees = Employee.all
    @employeemovements = EmployeeMovement.distinct_positions
  end

  def update_employee_movements
    if params[:employee_id]
      @employeemovements = [].insert(0, "Select Employee Movement")
    else
      employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
      @employeemovements = employee.employee_movements.map{ |a| [a.position, a.id] }.insert(0, "Select Employee Movement")
    end
  end

  def commendations
    emdates = EmployeeMovement.last_2_dates_obtained(params[:employee_movement_id])
    date_from = emdates[0].date_obtained
    date_to   = emdates.length == 1 ? nil : emdates[1].date_obtained
    emp = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
    @commendations = case date_to.nil?
                     when true then emp.commendations.this_day_onwards(date_from)
                     else           emp.commendations.within(date_from, date_to)
                     end
  end
end
```

What I'm trying to do here is, I'm creating a page filled with links and drop down lists that will serve as a Reports center. The idea is, each link will be catered by a controller. Each controller will be responsible in showing my PDF in the browser (through ThinReports, if you're curious).

The #employees_select change event is used for changing the value of the #employee_movements_select collection_select.

Now my problem is, how can i capture the value of both #employees_select and #employee_movements_select and pass them to my commendations action?

I tested link_to by hardcoding values, and it works (code below)

```
<%= link_to 'COMMENDATION', commendations_path(employee_id: 1, employee_movement_id: 12, format: 'pdf') %>
```

However, If I use javascript to push the values to my commendations action through the 'click' event, my commendations action will be called twice, thus an error occurs because the params[:employee_id] in the action is now blank.

By the way, I need those values because my *commendations* action needs it so I can populate my PDF report template.

Please help. Thanks a lot in advance!

## UPDATE 1

-> Updated link_to:

```
<%= link_to 'COMMENDATION', '#', { id: 'commendations_click' } %>
```

-> Removed dataType: "script" in #commendations_click event handler

-> Updated url: in #commendations_click event handler

```
url: <%= commendations_path(format: 'pdf') %>
```

## UPDATE 2 (RESOLUTION)

I tweaked my javascript to look something like this:

```
$('#commendations_click').click(function() {
  event.preventdefault();
  window.location = "<%=j commendations_path(format: 'pdf') %>" + "?employee_id=" + $('#employees_select').val() + "&amp;employee_movement_id=" + $('#employee_movements_select').val();
});
```

Works perfect now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things come to mind. You can wrap the two select lists within a form element and just do a submit. Everything inside the form will be submitted to your server and you can process the request and handle the redirect on the server side. The other thing you can do is to handle the commendations click event on the client side using jquery or something. Just bind to the click event of that link, grab the values of the two select lists and do whatever you want with it. Remember, link_to just gets rendered as plain old html links on the view. For e.g.

```
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile) gets rendered as <a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>
```

Comment: Hello Mahesh, thanks you for your reply. I will test your suggestions asap. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @mahesh, can i ask for an example on your second suggestion? I tried doing it in javascript but i ended up calling my commendation action twice for a single click...

Comment: @Sam-2695310 can you post what you have so far....maybe I can spot what the error is..

Comment: I've updated my question to be more specific. I've also shown there how I used the javascript to call my action. I found out my action was getting executed twice when I tried placing binding.pry, and it stopped there twice. Wild guess: is the duplication caused by the AJAX call and the link_to call?

Comment: Yes..your link shouldnt be doing anything...it should just be <a href='#' .....> the magic should happen in your jquery ajax call. I did notice two other things.. dataType: "script"  is not needed ..unless you are expecting a script back in the response...and I also dont see you doing anything with the response of the ajax call...you probably need a response handler for your ajax call..where you can handle the response..

Comment: Ok, kindly see UPDATE 1 above. Regarding the response to the ajax call, I have a view named commendations.pdf.thinreports. This file serves as the view after the evaluation of the commendations action since I indicated in the link_to url helper that format: 'pdf'. However, when using '#' as path to link_to, nothing happens.

Comment: In your    $('#commendations_click').click(function()  you don't need to make an ajax call...all you need to do is grab the values of the two select lists, create a URL where you want the user to go and issues a redirect in javascript.

Comment: I added this in the click event `window.location = "<%=j commendations_path(format: 'pdf') %>" 
        + "?employee_id=" + $('#employees_select').val() 
        + "&amp;employee_movement_id=" + $('#employee_movements_select').val()` and it worked. Is this acceptable (jquery bestpractice) to chop the address like this? I'll already accept this as the answer after your response to my last question. Thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: I don't see why this would be bad practice...but others folks might have an opinion. I dynamically create URLs and request parameters using jquery in my rails based application all the time..and I don't have a problem with it :)